# Uploading videos and document

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.3

I am a freshman using ruby-on-rails, I want to build a website that provides users tutor videos. The problem is how can I upload a video or document on my webpage using ruby-on rails, my strategy is to save a link for that video or document in the data base so when I open a page contains a video or document it will upload automatically.
I am using Postgresql 9.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tyry using paperclip gem
It will be easier, you can look into this link
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3